# Add an editor to a list of terminal system editors

Tags: command-line, configuration, environment-variables, text-editor

When you use `vipw` or `crontab` or just type `select-editor` you are presented with the list of the editors installed on the system. How do I add my custom editor to that list?

Answer (score 4):

To add an additional alternative application to the Debian alternatives system, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install link name path priority
```

To add an additional editor, run a command as:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/your-custom-editor 50
```

where the third entry after `--install` is the executable of your custom editor. The first entry is the generic command that loads the selected editor, the second the name of the group of alternative applications. The number must be given and indicates a priority.

After that, you should be able to select your custom editor with either `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` or `sudo select-editor`.

You can learn more about the [Debian alternatives system here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).